# 90s historical kids show where people get sucked into a computer?

Tags: story-identification, tv, history

I remember some sort of 90s kids history show. Kids would put a floppy into an 90s era computer and then gets sucked into the computer where they would interview various historical figures.

Comment: Was this on US TV? Canadian? British, Australian, other?

Comment: It was American I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Could be [A.J.'s Time Travelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.J.%27s_Time_Travelers).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you identify which episode in particular the OP is looking for?

Comment: that is the one.

Comment: That was the format of each episode. I don't see where OP is asking for a particular episode.